For a bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3$, does the Besov space $B^{1/2,6/5}_{4/3}(\Omega)$ belong to $L^2$?
According to the formula, we have the real interpolation
\begin{equation}
(L^{6/5}(\Omega), W^{2,6/5}\Omega))_{1/4,4/3} = B^{1/2,6/5}_{4/3}(\Omega).
\end{equation}
for any bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3$.
However, this Besov space $B^{1/2,6/5}_{4/3}(\Omega)$ is quite elusive to me...For example, which $L^p$ space does it belong to? Do we have $B^{1/2,6/5}_{4/3}(\Omega) \subset L^2(\Omega)$?
Could anyone please clarify for me?

So for a Besov space of the form $B^{s,p}_q$ (sometimes written $B^s_{p,q}$), the index $s$ can be thought of as the number of derivatives, the index $p$ as the $L^p$ norm of integrability, and the $q$ is a refined regularity index which can be seen as a logarithmic correction (For example, $1/|x|$ is not in $L^1$, but almost, up to a logarithmic divergence of the integral). More precisely, for $1\leq q_1 \leq q_2$ and $1\leq p$ and $s>0$ and $\epsilon>0$, the following continuous embeddings hold
$$
W^{s+\epsilon,p} \subseteq B^{s,p}_{1} \subseteq B^{s,p}_{q_1} \subseteq B^{s,p}_{q_2}\subseteq B^{s,p}_{\infty} \subseteq W^{s-\epsilon,p} \subseteq L^p
$$
Moreover, by Sobolev embeddings, regularity implies better integrability in the sense that
$$
B^{s,p}_{q} \subseteq B^{0,p^*}_{q}
$$
with $\frac{1}{p*} = \frac{1}{p}-\frac{s}{3}$, and finally, for fixed $n\in\mathbb N_0$ and $p$, the classical Sobolev spaces fit inside the Besov scale in the following sense: for $p\leq 2$,
$$
B^{n,p}_p \subseteq W^{n,p} \subseteq B^{n,p}_2
$$
and this is reversed if $p\geq 2$ (in particular, $B^{s,2}_2 = H^s$). Notice that I used the convention $W^{0,p} = L^p$.
In your particular case, you therefore get since $p=4/3$, $s=1/2$ and $4/3 < 3/2$,
$$
B^{1/2,6/5}_{4/3} \subseteq B^{0,3/2}_{4/3} \subseteq B^{0,3/2}_{3/2} \subseteq L^{3/2}
$$
Since the domain is bounded, it of course also implies the embedding in $L^p$ for any $p\leq 3/2$.

Great answer! The $q$ index in Besov spaces always threw me off as to what it's actually doing; your explanation helps a lot!

Thank you. Could you also provide any reference for the embedding theorems you used?

@Jose27 Perhaps do you recognize which references have been used for this wonderful answer?

I don't have the precise references for each embedding in mind, but Triebel's books Theory of function spaces II (or also the I) should contain most of that and references. A lighter exposition (but in $\Bbb R^d$) is in Bahouri, Chemin, Danchin Fourier Analysis and Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations
